# How to set the vehicle departSpeed in veins/omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I would like to set the departSpeed of each car (mobility node) in veins/omnet++ to be the max allowed speed of the lane. I've already configured it in the SUMO route as follow:
`<vehicle id="myflow.0" type="normal car" depart="0.79" departLane="free" departSpeed="max">`
However, in the simulation, the vehicle still departs from speed 0. Do I have to set the departSpeed in the omnetpp.ini file?

Now I modified the route file, but only the first car can depart at the max speed, while for the rest cars, they don't even accelerate. The following is my route file:

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/routes_file.xsd">
<vType id="normal car" maxSpeed="40.00" speedFactor="1.0" vClass="passenger" carFollowModel="Krauss" accel="2.6" decel="4.5" sigma="0.5" />
<route id="route0" edges="0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12"/>
<vehicle id="myflow.0" type="normal car" depart="0.79" route="route0" departLane="free" departSpeed="max"/>
<vehicle id="myflow.1" type="normal car" depart="1.83" route="route0" departLane="free" departSpeed="max"/>
<vehicle id="myflow.2" type="normal car" depart="2.36" route="route0" departLane="free" departSpeed="max"/>
<vehicle id="myflow.3" type="normal car" depart="2.75" route="route0" departLane="free" departSpeed="max"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It is because I set the `vechileNumber` in the `omnetpp.ini`, as follow: `#*.manager.numVehicles = 1000`. Once I remove this, the simulation works as expected. I guess the reason is when I set the vehicleNumber in the `omnetpp.ini`, then this number of vehicles (nodes) will be created by TraCI in addition to the number of vehicles created in SUMO. Also, the initial settings, e.g., the speed, are not controlled by SUMO, but depend on the TraCI module settings.

Comment: This is correct. Either SUMO (through its .rou.xml file) or OMNeT++ (through the .ini parameter numVehicles) or both can create vehicles.

Comment: For the vehicles created by OMNeT++, where are the initial values set, such as departSpeed, departLane, and is it possible to customize them in the `omnetpp.ini` file?

Comment: They are added in https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L608, so this is the point to make modifications to depart speed etc. See https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L33 for the full list of parameters.